# "'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'" in ComplexDateTimeField conversion

Tags: string, mongodb, mongoengine, strftime

Well, I'm implementing a testcase in service, but I'm facing some problems.

Here's a sample of the code

```
datetime_one = mongo.ComplexDateTimeField()._convert_from_string('2019, 12, 20, 19, 24, 10, 451923')

visitor = Visit()
visitor.user_id = '750645c7-bf66-4023-9a2d-9c942a25f6cd'
visitor.timestamp = mongo.ComplexDateTimeField().to_mongo(datetime_one)
visitor.save()
```

visitor is an object from the class Visit:

```
from datetime import datetime
import mongoengine as mongo

class Visit(mongo.Document):

    user_id = mongo.UUIDField(required=True)
    timestamp = mongo.ComplexDateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
```

When I try run this code I get error in the line of visitor.timestamp...

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This looks like Python, but you should add an according tag. Also, please extract and provide a [mcve]. It may as well be relevant what's in your DB, so add a snippet to fill a test collection as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `datetime` instances, not strings and you don't need to use `to_mongo` or `_convert_from_string`.

As described in the doc of the [ComplexDateTimeField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ComplexDateTimeField), the only difference with a regular DateTimeField is that the date will be stored as a string behind the scene but any interaction you have with the attribute will be with a `datetime`.

See below:

```
class Visit(Document):
    timestamp = ComplexDateTimeField()

visit = Visit(timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
visit.save()
assert isinstance(visit.timestamp, datetime)

# print object as it is stored in mongodb
print(Visit.objects.as_pymongo())
# Output: [{'timestamp': '2020,01,23,22,24,21,449017', '_id': ObjectId('5e2a1d15f3ede875e9c0b806')}]
```

Feel free to look at the corresponding [test file](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/tests/fields/test_complex_datetime_field.py) if you want more code samples.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I thought I should convert it. Thank you for the explanation!